# Using class attribute as array-bound

Tags: c++, class

I would like to do this:

```
Class Obj{
private:
int a;
int b[a][3];

public:
Obj(int a);
}
```

So that i can specify the size of my array when creating my object.But I get this compilation error:    *error: array bound is not an integer constant*

I don't want to use vectors, dos anyone know how I can do this? 
Thanks.

Comment: If you're not using vectors, welcome to the painful world of dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: As @chris says .. you need to do it your self with the new operator or malloc.

Comment: It's even worse in a class because you have to fill in three or five new members.

Comment: Have to mention it: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/02/06/10391383.aspx

Comment: Well the reason I dont wan't to use vectors is that I don't now how to deal with vectors of array. In this i would like an array of 'a' arrays of size 3...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array size should be `constant`. There is only one way, without dynamic allocation - use predefined constant for all arrays of this class.

```
class Obj{
private:
static constexr int a = 5;
int b[a][3];

public:
Obj();
};
```

If you want different sizes, then you should allocate memory dynamically, if you don't use vectors.

Comment: What's the point of indicating 'a' in ;y constructor if it's constant ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a dynamic allocation:

```
b = new int *[a] ;
//memory allocated for  elements of each column.
for( int i = 0 ; i < a ; i++ )
   b[i] = new int[3];
```

Comment: Might as well keep it at `int (*b)[3]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to depend on extension then ISO C99 allows variable length arrays through extension, have a look at it http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html, with this  extension arrays are declared like any other automatic arrays, but with a length that is not a constant expression.

Side effect is your code will compile with compile which got this extension.